# Time complexity of finding kth largest element in n sorted arrays using quickselect

Tags: arrays, sorting

If you have `J`sorted arrays of length `N`, find the `kth` smallest element among them. 
There are a few potential solutions here, some involving a min heap or binary search, but I want to know what the time complexity would be for using quickselect. If we simply concatenated each of the arrays together and used quickselect on the combined array.

Quickselect runs in linear time in the average case, but the combining of arrays does expand the search space, but it is more efficient than using a merging strategy because quickselect necessarily allows some elements to be ignored if you choose good pivots.

Answer (score 1):

Quickselect is very similar to quicksort because of its divide-and-conquer strategy. The difference between the 2 is that Quickselect will only recur for the part of the data that holds the kth 
smallest element and will continue until the interval is equal to k value, which means it has found the kth smallest value (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quickselect-algorithm/). In regards to your question, I think you are right when you say it depends on the pivot that you get when you are recurring. In the best case it would the time would still take O(n) (because Quickselect only searches 1 part of the split data and the size of n depend on your dataset) and in the worst case O(n^2) for when a bad pivot is selected. In order for this algorithm to be generalized it would be difficult to find the "best possible" pivot for each grouping of data.

When looking at using a heap as the method first when given the data it would take O(n) time to build the heap in the first place. And in order to find the kth smallest item, the min element in the heap, the root, must be found k times. Removing the min in a min heap only takes 1 team, but heapifying the heap after the root is removed would take O(logn) time which could add up to be quite costly depending on this input size you are discussing. So total time for the heap method would be O(1) + O(klogn) where k is the kth smallest number.

Basically the difference in efficiency really depends on how the pivots would be selected in Quickselect and how big the input is or the k value when thinking about the heap method.